# Pandas: use apply function based on another column condition

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to use `apply()` function on first column for only particular cases of values from second column.

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
URL      text  
-------  ---------
URL1     
URL2     some text
```

I want to use `apply()` function on the `URL` column when `text` is blank (or some other condition). I have tried this

```
webdata['text'] = webdata.apply(lambda row: func(row['URL']) if row['text']== '' else row['text'])
```

`func()` is my function I want to call. But I get this error.

> ('text', u'occurred at index key')

Is there any mistake, or is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
webdata.loc[webdata['text']=='', 'text'] = \
    webdata.loc[webdata['text']=='', 'URL'].apply(func)
```

Comment: This is a workaround. It doesn't solve the general problem of using data from one column inside the apply method acting on another column.